# Jenkins job DSL - get jenkins to checkout a specific commit

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I simply need to put together a job that checks-out the same commit every time.

Checking the docs, I can't seem to find a way to do it:

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.scm-git

```
// checkout repo1 to a sub directory and clean the workspace after checkout
job('example-1') {
scm {
    git {
        remote {
            name('remoteB')
            url('git@server:account/repo1.git')
        }
        extensions {
            cleanAfterCheckout()
            relativeTargetDirectory('repo1')
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to do something like commit('hash') somewhere in that block.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the commit using the branch setting.

```
// checkout repo1 to a sub directory and clean the workspace after checkout
job('example-1') {
  scm {
    git {
      remote {
        name('remoteB')
        url('git@server:account/repo1.git')
      }
      branch('hash')
      extensions {
        cleanAfterCheckout()
        relativeTargetDirectory('repo1')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am already using branch to specify the branch from github, does what you suggest work because a hash is unique per branch? So the branch is implicitly declared? Thanks!

Comment: A branch in git is basically just a pointer to a commit. In Job DSL context the `branch()` option can be used to specify a branch, tag or commit.

Comment: Makes sense, that's why it's not mentioned in [the docs](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.scm.GitContext.branch)

Comment: I ended up branching off and using a proper branch nobosy messes up with. If you know for sure your solution works I will accept it :)

Comment: Sounds like a good choice :) When manually configuring a freestyle job the help text tells that branch, tag, commit, wildcards etc are supported.